c# find word and parts of that word seperated by spaces
I have a lot of texts and a search term, for example 'simcard'. I then want all places where 'simcard' appears, but also 'sim card', for example.
How should I achieve that?
You can of course delete the spaces from all texts you search. And then find the text with text.IndexOf('simcard') or text.Contains('simcard'). Then I detect the texts that contain 'simcard', 'sim card' etc.
But I also want to highlight all occurrences later in the list of texts. How do I find the position of, for example, 'SIM card'?

Why are you keen to avoid "or"? If it's for performance, why not seek "sim" and them check whether it's "simcard" or "sim card" ?

You could use a regex for that.
e.g. var capture = new Regex("sim[ ]?card").match(yourString)

I solved it by using FreeText.

I would recommend using Regex for such operations, as long as high performance is not a requirement.
A possible solution would be:
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
//...
static void GetPositions()
{
    string input = "Foo Bar SimCard SIM card.";
    string pattern = @"(?i)sim\s?card";

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    Match match = regex.Match(input);

    while (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found '{match.Value}' at position {match.Index}");
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
}

Edit:
Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-regex before implementing.

If it was just the word 'SIM card' it wouldn't be that difficult. But it can be many words!

I figured out that I could use camelCase. Parts of the word that begin with a capital letter may be preceded by a space. I created a method that creates a regex expression of the search term and precedes capital letters with '\s?'.
For example, userName results in the regex expression "(?i)user\s?Name".
I want to use the regex in a Linq expression:
Regex regex = new Regex("(?i)user\s?Name");
var temp1 = from DatabaseUser usr in dataContext.DatabaseUsers select usr;

var temp2 = from usr in temp1 let matches = regex.Matches(usr.Description)
            where matches.Count > 0
            select((DatabaseUser)usr);

But when I run the following statement:
var temp3 = temp2.ToList();

I get the following error message:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection Matches(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
How should I solve this?
